# How to send keys or button presses to an app via powershell when the screen is locked

Tags: powershell, winapi

I have an application that needs to be deployed to numerous systems that does not have any switches and does not accept any input.  Because of this i have created a script that calls the app via win32 native methods to maximize the window and hide the window after sending keys.  i am using the Wscript.Shell object to call the app and send hot keys to it to press the buttons.  All this is working fine but i just realized it doesn't work at all when the screen is locked, which makes sense because it is just pressing the keys basically. I have since tried using system.windows.forms.sendkeys to send the keys to app and when the screen is locked, an access denied message is returned. 
Is it possible to send keys to an app or button presses via powershell when the screen is locked?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview)?

Comment: Because I didn't know it existed or how I would use it.

Comment: You probably won't have luck finding a way to send keys to an application while the workstation is locked. That would be a security hole. If the application's only interface is through UI, you probably won't even be able to start it without a logged in user (unattended).

Comment: Thats what it looks like.  Thanks

Comment: If the desktop is locked then user input is not allowed (that is the whole point in locking the desktop).  You will not overcome this when using a method that simulates user input (SendKeys).

Comment: Can you tell me what press the buttons do?Maybe you can try another way to avoid press the button(SendKeys).

Comment: @ric: What sort of security hole do you have in mind? What security implications does automating an application in a locked desktop have as opposed to automating an application in an interactive session?

Comment: An application that has access to send keys to a locked workstation could do anything on the user's behalf without the user knowing: open a browser, navigate to a malicious site, download malware, etc. 
Sending keys while the user is logged in is more likely to be noticed by the user, and more likely to be interrupted by an active user.

Comment: @ric: An application that was authorized by the user to automate other applications is trusted by the user. It can do anything, regardless of whether a user has locked their desktop or not. This is not a security issue, much like a user observing unwanted actions does not provide any sort of safety.

Comment: @strive sun - MSFT the key presses are hotkeys Ctrl space to push a continue button, then tab three times Ctrl space to push update button.  I would be running the script as system account not a specific user.

Comment: That's brittle. If you want a solution that's immune to - say - the target application reordering its tabs, use UI Automation. It's also immune to a user suddenly deciding to use their computer, while your code is running.

Comment: Is that a .net class I can use? I don't see anything on using it with powershell  except an old module that uses it but can't tell what it's leveraging.  I'd like to be able to just use the methods it has in powershell and not the module

Comment: Using PowerShell to simulate keys doesn't work, you may need to follow @IInspectable said,  try UI Automation.

Comment: Ya i finally found a few things on adding the assemblies to powershell, all though i couldnt get add-type to work with uiatomation.  When i get the root the element of the process though and try to find the button using getclickablepoint method it tells me the automation element has no clickable point.  Its like it is not picking up the buttons in the app.

Comment: That method may not be the correct way to get a button actually, but i tried using accessibility insights tool on the app and when i hightlight the window there are no groups for anything.  It actually shows it as a "pane" not a window. If i click the button nothing is shown for it.  If i do the same thing with calculator and highlight one of the number keys accessibility insights shows a child group under the window name that has all the buttons 1-9 under that group and what the names are for them. Calculator app is shown as a "window" instead. I dont think UIAutomation will work.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution to simulate the keystrokes and button click is posting the messages directly to the application. Below is the sample code to simulate pressed 'a'(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) about virtual-key codes) character in a notepad window, and it also works well when the screen is locked down or the notepad window is not active.

```
HWND hNotepad=(HWND)0x502c8;
unsigned int key = 0x41;//A key
unsigned int scanCode = MapVirtualKey(key, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
while (true)
{
    unsigned int lParamKeyDown = 0x01 | (scanCode << 16) | 0x00000000;
    PostMessage(hNotepad, WM_KEYDOWN, key, lParamKeyDown);
    Sleep(100);
    unsigned int lParamKeyUp = 0x01 | (scanCode << 16) | 0xc0000000;
    PostMessage(hNotepad, WM_KEYUP, key, lParamKeyUp);
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

To get the detailed of message for simulating, you can use Spy++ to monitor the messages generate by keyboards pressing.

And below is an blog about how to interact Windows API in PowerShell:

[Use PowerShell to Interact with the Windows API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/)